# Drop down menu styling issue across browsers

Tags: wordpress, safari, dropdown

I have an issue with a website being programmed in WordPress. A drop down menu is showing correct in Chrome but not in Safari. See attached images, we want a clean drop down with symbol ∨ and not with arrows.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Best,
Don

[Correct drop down as shown in Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aJhan.jpg)

[Incorrect drop down as shown in Safari](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dKvMb.jpg)

Comment: hi Don, we need to see what you've done in order to be able to explain how it works. it looks like you're just letting the browser use its own dropdown menu, which are different in chrome and safari. you'll probably need to make a custom dropdown input or use something like bootstrap or material-ui

Answer (score 0):

Inputs have a default style on each browser, this is normal behaviour, you should take a look at this stackoverflow article [How do I style a <select> dropdown with only CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895476/how-do-i-style-a-select-dropdown-with-only-css) to customize it accross all browsers.

Remember also to do some research first before asking question, most of the time, answers are already out there.